# Which Bluetooth Headphones Switch Easily between 3 Devices?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

I am planning on buying bluetooth headphones that I would use alternatively with my iPad, iPhone and MacBook Pro. I saw the bose headphones allow to have 2 devices connected at the same time and that it is easy to switch from one to the other but it's only with two.

Which Bluetooth Headphones are able to switch easily between 3 different devices?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Bluetooth Multipoint only allows two devices to be connected at the same time.

There are some business headsets that can connect to three devices at once, but they cheat - they use Bluetooth multipoint to the phone and ipad and use DECT to connect to a base station on your desk. The base station can connect to the macbook with a USB cable.

Answer (score 3):

[AirPods](https://www.apple.com/airpods/)!

1. You can switch devices easily

   - Airplay in apps that support it
   - iPhone Control Center: Swipe Up, Swipe Right to Left, select AirPods in Airplay on bottom
   - iPhone Bluetooth: Force Touch "Settings", select Bluetooth, connect
   - Mac Bluetooth in Menu Bar (if not there, go to System Preferences → Bluetooth → "Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar"
   - Mac Sound in Menu Bar (System Preferences → Sound → "Show Volume in Menu Bar")
2. AirPods auto-pair to devices signed into the same Apple ID (no need to pair via Bluetooth). It connects to the last connected device automatically.
3. Sound quality/fit are essentially identical to traditional Earpods, but Airpods are truly wireless!

Answer (score 2):

I found yesterday that Bose qc35 series 2 has easy switching mode between all previously connected devices at easy of single move.

I found the related [help page here](https://www.bose.co.uk/en_gb/support/article/switching-between-previously-paired-devices-soundlink-ae-headphones-ii.html).

Bad side is this, it's a very big headphone for me to constantly use.